# Batch file Filename creates folder and txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf

I am looking to create a batch file that creates a folder, subfolder, and txt file.

I often receive a group of pdf files that I have to review and import into isqft Takeoff.

My usual procedure is to create a folder named after the pdf. Move pdf into folder. Create a txt file with same name. Create a folder named Split. Open PDF in PDFSam and split every page into the Split folder. Extract the bookmarks into the txt file. Use Renamer to rename the split PDFs from teh txt file.

Is there a way to batch this? Or should I focus on a few batch files to complete this? I have searched on here for a solution, but honestly the commands/syntax for batch files really confuse me. I am mainly looking for the folder creation, subfolder creation, txt creation, and if at all possible, the PDFSam splitting.

What is usually received,

```
/Apartments/plans/Arch.pdf
/Apartments/plans/Civil.pdf
/Apartments/plans/Irrigation.pdf
/Apartments/plans/Landscape.pdf
/Apartments/plans/MEP.pdf
/Apartments/plans/Structural.pdf
```

How it looks after I mess with everything

```
/Apartments/plans/Arch/Arch.pdf
/Apartments/plans/Arch/Arch.txt
/Apartments/plans/Arch/Split/File_0001.pdf,File_0002.pdf,etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the basic stuff you can use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "source=C:\Apartments\plans"
FOR %%F IN ("%source%\"*.pdf) DO (
    echo %%F
    mkdir "!source!\%%~nF"
    mkdir "!source!\%%~nF\split"
    move "%%F" "!source!\%%~nF"
    type nul> "!source!\%%~nF\%%~nF.txt"
)
pause
```

This creates the folder, textfile, subfolder, and moves the pdfs

For the splitting you should use http://www.sejda.org/, which is the command-line version of PDFSaM.

Comment: Dennis,  Thanks for this. I looked up and made the source relative as this will fit my need better. I just tried it and it will save me a lot of time. I will look into sejda to finish the rest of what i am looking for.

Comment: @mtdingee If my answer solved your problem, you can click the check to the left of it to mark it as correct. If you're still having trouble implementing the splitting just leave a comment and I'll try to help

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. The answer is correct. I am looking into the splitting right now, and will let you know if i have any questions. Thanks.